# AngularJs2 + Typescript and Visual Studio2013 with Es6

Tags: visual-studio, angular, ecmascript-6, typescript1.5

Is it possible to use it with es6 annotations and all the new cool features? Inside the Typescript owner ide?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Right Click on your project, Click on "Unload Project", then Right click and "Edit Project", Add this following line to your initial properties section and you should be seeing the ES6 annotations.

```
 <TypeScriptTarget>ES6</TypeScriptTarget>
```

I am using ES5 and I am not comfortable moving to ES6 yet.